# Pine Connector - Manage Trades on an individual basis

Tags: pine-script

we have a problem I am wondering if anyone can help with: We have Trade set up in Trading View that will take up multiple trades/positions on a strong trend and open these positions on MT4 via pine connector, we would like each of these positions to have a 1R target, but as far as we can see pine connector only allows to manage close on all trades, not on a individual trade basis. Is there anyway around this? So we can close each trade only close when it reaches its 1R target?

Answer (score 1):

You can close your positions partially (percentage based). So, you need to do some calculations and find out how much of your total position size you would like to close.

> **closelongpct**
> Close a percentage of buy positions (based on your
> initial volume), using your selected partial close percentage in the
> EA (25%, 34%, and 50%).
>
> `LicenseID,closelongpct,EURUSD`

Comment: Very interesting, thanks for that - had not thought of that approach.

Comment: can I ask - can we just use the the following id parameter to pick out the position to be closed: strategy.close(id, when, comment, qty, qty_percent, alert_message

Comment: Yes, that would work on Tradingview's side. But I don't think it would help you with the Pineconnector part of it.

Comment: Whar's your plan exactly?

Comment: like if we send the id for the trade to pine connector with market order to close,  would that not close the individual trade. We are trying to avoid closing all the trades, just pick out the ones on MT4 that meet the target criteria in trading view.

Comment: No, pineconnector wouldn't know anything about your order ids on Tradingview.

Comment: okay - so there is no way to pass the order id to pine connector - okay thanks

Answer (score 0):

For those who come accross this ticket later, see response directly from Pineconnector on this. 9th Dec 2022:
As for closing individual positions/trades, it is not available with the current EA though we will implement them in the next-gen of PineConnector. We are targetting early 2023 for its launch